# How to access the elements of a sparse matrix efficiently in Eigen library?

Tags: stl, sparse-matrix, eigen, unordered-map

I have filled in a sparse matrix A using Eigen library. Then I need to access the non-zero elements of the sparse matrix, if I perform it as A(rowindex,colindex), it will be very slow.

I also try to use the unordered_map in stl to solve this problem, it is also very slow.

Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the "Iterating over the nonzero coefficients" section in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html

Comment: This can not solve my problem. I need to access the nonzero elemnts in an unsorted way, not row-wise or column-wise. For example, I access the elemnts A(3,2), A(4,3), A(1,4), A(8,2).........

Comment: If you use `A.coeff(rowindex,colindex)` Eigen performs a binary search (see Andrew's answer) bounded by the column index (assuming ColMajor) to see if the element exists, and returns it if it does or a zero otherwise. Therefore, this is probably already optimized in Eigen. If you know something about the sparsity pattern of the matrix, like the number of nonzeros in each column, then you can do a little better. For instance, if you wanted to grab the first nonzero value in column "colindex": `A.valuePtr()[A.outerIndexPtr()[colindex]]`

Answer (score 0):

Compressed sparse matrices are stored in CSR or CSC format. Considering how a CSR matrix stores entries internally, there is an array storing x nonzero values, a corresponding array of length x storing their respective column location, and an array (usually much smaller than the other two) "pointing" to where rows change in those arrays.

There is no way to know where each nonzero element is, or if a row-column pair exists without *searching* for it in the two ordered arrays of rows (outer index) and columns (inner index). This isn't very efficient for accessing elements in an random way.